# AS3: Refer to different arrays dynamically?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

This might be a simple one, and if it is I'm sure I'll feel stupid.

Basically, I have arrays a1, a2 and a3.

Using a for statement..

```
for (var i 0; i < 4; i++) {
//stuff
}
```

How can I push data in the for statement into one of these arrays using i? That is, each time adding the data into the next group up. a[0] -> a[1] etc. I tried getDefinitionByName but it seems that only works for library objects!

Sorry if it's simple!

Cheers in advance.

EDIT:

The code in full where I need this to work. This is what I tried using the first answer I was given.

```
var fullList:Vector.<Array> = new Vector.<Array>();

for (var i1 = 0; i1 < 3; i1++)
{
    fullList.push(new Array());
}

var levelLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
levelLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, levelLoaded);
function levelLoaded(e:Event):void
{
    var indexcount = 0;
    txttileArray = e.target.data.split("a");
    txtDebug.text = txttileArray.toString();
    for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++)
    {
        temparray1 = txttileArray[indexcount].split("");
        for (var row = 0; row < temparray1.length; row ++)
        {
            var a = getDefinitionByName(temparray1[row] + "Tile") as Class;
            //trace(a);
            var b = new a  ;
            b.x = 17 + 17 * row;
            b.y = 17 + 17 * indexcount;
            addChild(b);
            fullList[indexcount].push(b);
        }
        indexcount++;
    }
}
```

sorry for the messy variable names.

Comment: Your question is confusing me a bit. Do you want to know how to access each separate array dynamically, or do you want to know how to pass i as an index into an array?

Comment: i want to know how to access each separate array dynamically.

Comment: Still can't understand what you want. You mind explaining exactly what you are trying to do in a way that can actually be understood?

Comment: i have three arrays, a1, a2 and a3. i want to be able access these arrays based on the value of the variable "i". so for example, if "i" is 1, i want to push a data value to a1. and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i have three arrays, a1, a2 and a3. i want to be able access these
>   arrays based on the value of the variable "i". so for example, if "i"
>   is 1, i want to push a data value to a1. and so on – hazdog

This is not possible if you have arrays a1, a2 and a3 as local (defined in the function) variables. If they are defined in the class, then here's how you do it:

```
private var a1:Array=[];
private var a2:Array=[];
private var a3:Array=[];

private function pushValue(identifier:String, value:Object):int {
    var name:String="a" + identifier;
    var target:Array=this[name] as Array;
    if(target == null) {
        throw new Error("No such array " + name);
    } else {
        return target.push(value);
    }
}

//And then call it like this:
pushValue("1", "This value goes in array a1");
pushValue("1", "This is another value that goes in array a1");

pushValue("2", "This value goes in array a1");
pushValue("2", "This is another value that goes in array a2");

pushValue("3", "This value goes in array a3");
pushValue("3", "This is another value that goes in array a3");
```

Otherwise, you can define an array of arrays (or vector of arrays), say `holderArray` in which you put your target arrays, and then push the value to `holderArray[identifier]`

**EDIT**
Instead of defining `a1`, `a2` and `a3` in the `this` object, define it like this:

```
private var arrayHolder:Object={};

private function init():void {
    for(var i:int=1; i<=3; i++) {
        arrayHolder["a" + i]=new Array();
    }
}

init();
```

Then, your arrays will be stored as `arrayHolder.a1`, `arrayHolder.a2`, `arrayHolder.a3` etc
And modify pushValue as follows:
Change

```
var target:Array=this[name] as Array;
```

to

```
var target:Array=arrayHolder[name] as Array;
```

Comment: as with the other solution someone posted, doing this results in my arrays being blank. no error is being thrown, just that the arrays are coming up blank

Comment: Can only happen if you're reinitializing the arrays. Check that.

Comment: just changed up my code a little.. now it says "no such array a1".. but the third line of my program initialises a1 as a new array. gah!

Comment: by the way, this is on timeline, i haven't yet put things into a class, i'm a bit dodgy like that. i'll try out your new solution and get back to you, but chances are i'll have gone to bed before i get a chance to reply. thanks for the help. e: just tested, still can't push anything into the arrays. will i need to put this into a class for this to work? i am more than capable but have been slightly lazy with this project

Comment: yes, i removed the "this" and was able to get the "target" variable to work correctly, however it then decided to throw an error and say a1 couldn't be found -- even though a1 had already been declared!

Comment: Do you have a debugger? You should use one

Comment: i use the built in debugger in flash pro cs5.5. anyway, i played around with it a bit today and got it working, if i recall correctly the problem was the placement / scope of your function in my program. regardless, i fixed the problem using this solution. many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Inception.

You need to use Array in Array.

```
private var fullList:Vector.<Array>;
private var total:uint = 4;

function a():void
{
    // first creating array list
    fullList = new Vector.<Array>();

    for (var i:uint = 0; i < total; i++)
    {
        fullList.push(new Array());
    }
}

function b():void
{
    // doing the stuff

    for (var i:uint = 0; i < total; i++)
    {
        switch (i)
        {
            case 0:

                fullList[i].push('zero-array-push');
                break;

            case 1:

                fullList[i].push('one-array-push');
                break;

            case 2:

                fullList[i].push('two-array-push');
                break;

            case 3:

                fullList[i].push('three-array-push');
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: wow, seems more complex than i thought.. i've not worked with vectors before, is there a way to do it without that? if not, i'll give this a shot and let you know how i go

Comment: Basically Vector is same as Array, just you can define which type of objects will be inside. Faster and better for autocomplete function.

Comment: I see. The problem is I'm already working with a 2D array for navigation around a grid-like field.. Having tried both a vector and an array of arrays, i can't seem to push the data into the array correctly, which is causing error for this movement. i'll post what I have at the bottom of my question